# If/if - else/ else with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stream

I'm writing a small piece of logic that checks if Facebook API retrieves the user email for me, if not, I'm setting the email from request parameter, or if that isn't present either, I'm throwing an exception . 
My question is that would you change anything aesthetically to make it look nicer based on Java 8 - Lambda conventions?

```
       {
            UserProfile newUser = new     UserProfile(fbUser.getId());
            if( null == fbUser.getEmail() ) {     newUser.setEmail(userMail); }
            if( null == newUser.getEmail() ) { throw new MissingServletRequestParameterException("email", "String"); }
            newUser.setEmail(fbUser.getEmail());
            newUser.setUsername(fbUser.getName());
            newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(fbReq.getAccessToken()));
            newUser.setFirebaseToken(fbReq.getFirebaseToken());
            newUser.setLanguage(HoopLocale.getById(locale.getLanguage().toLowerCase()).toString());

            UserAccount acc = new UserAccount();
            acc.setCurrency(currencyRepo.findById(CurrencyName.getById(fbReq.getCurrency()).getId())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Currency id", "id", fbReq.getCurrency())));
            newUser.setUserAccount(acc);

            userRepository.save(newUser);
        }
```

Comment: This might be a better fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ifPresentOrElse (introduced in Java 9):

```
Optional.ofNullable(userMail)
.ifPresentOrElse(newUser::setEmail, () -> {throw new MissingServletRequestParameterException("email", "String");});
```

to replace this part of you code:

```
if( null == fbUser.getEmail() ) {     newUser.setEmail(userMail); }
if( null == newUser.getEmail() ) { throw new MissingServletRequestParameterException("email", "String"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Optional`s but note that whether this looks "nicer" is arguable.

```
newUser.setEmail(
    Optional.ofNullable(fbUser.getEmail())
        .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(userMail)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new MissingServletRequestParameterException("email", "String")))
);
```

Comment: I like it very much, thanks! :)

Comment: Done, thanks for notifying, I'm kind of new here. :)